# testing angularjs $httpbackend and $resource

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

***Update - see end of post***

I have a controller that depends on a service. the service encapsulates `$resource`. Here is the code

```
app.controller('charactersController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, marvelRepository) {
    var page = parseInt($routeParams.pageNumber);

    marvelRepository.fetch(page - 1).then(function (data) {
        $scope.characters = data.results;
        $scope.paging = {
            page: page,
            total: data.total,
            pageSize: data.limit
        };
    });

    $scope.goto = function (pageNumber) {
        $location.path('/characters/' + pageNumber);
    };
});

marvel.service('marvelRepository', function (hash, $resource) {
    var extended = ng.extend(hash.authenticate(), { id: '@id' });
    var characters = $resource('http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/:id', extended);

    return {
        get: function (characterId) {
            return characters
                .get({ id: characterId })
                .$promise
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.code !== 200) {
                        throw response;
                    }

                    return response.data.results[0];
                });
        },
        fetch: function (pageIndex) {
            return characters
                .get({ limit: 20, offset: pageIndex * 20 })
                .$promise
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.code !== 200) {
                        throw response;
                    }

                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

the hash dependency creates authentication parameters for the marvel api: public key, timestamp & hash value.

The website work and I can display a list of characters. Now I'm trying to write tests (because angular promotes easy testablity....)

Here is my test

```
describe("Angular Demo - Test", function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('demo'));

    describe('requiring Marvel respository', function() {
        var url = 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=123&hash=abc123&limit=20&offset=0&ts=20140601073322';
        var httpBackend, location, scope, controller;

        beforeEach(module(function (hashProvider) {
            hashProvider.override({
                apikey: '123',
                ts: '20140601073322',
                hash: 'abc123'
            });
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, $location, $rootScope, $controller) {
            controller = $controller;
            location = $location;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        }));

        afterEach(function () {
            //httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            //httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        describe('charactersController', function () {
            var characters;

            beforeEach(function() {
                characters = new Array(20);

                httpBackend.when('get', url).respond({ data: { results: characters, offset: 2, limit: 20, total: 100 } });

            });

            it('should be able to get a page of characters', function () {
                httpBackend.expect('get', url);

                controller('charactersController', { $scope: scope, $routeParams: { pageNumber: 1 } });

                httpBackend.flush();

                expect(scope.characters).toBe(characters);
            });

            it('should be able to configure paging', function () {
                 httpBackend.expect('get', url);

                controller('charactersController', { $scope: scope, $routeParams: { pageNumber: 1 } });

                httpBackend.flush();

                expect(scope.paging.total).toBe(100);
                expect(scope.paging.page).toBe(1);
                expect(scope.paging.pageSize).toBe(20);
            });

            it('should be able to navigate to another page of characters', function () {
                controller('charactersController', { $scope: scope });

                scope.goto(5);

                expect(location.path()).toBe('/characters/5');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

when I execute the tests I get the following results

> Error: Unexpected request: GET
>   http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1?apikey=123&hash=abc123&ts=20140601073322
>
> Expected get
>   http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1?apikey=123&hash=abc123&ts=20140601073322
>
> Error: Unexpected request: GET
>   http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1?apikey=123&hash=abc123&ts=20140601073322
>
> Expected get
>   http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1?apikey=123&hash=abc123&ts=20140601073322
>       at $httpBackend (/tests/angular-mock.js:1172:13)
>       at sendReq (/js/angular/angular.js:8286:9)
>       at $http.serverRequest (/js/angular/angular.js:8027:16)
>       at wrappedCallback (/js/angular/angular.js:11574:81)
>       at wrappedCallback (/js/angular/angular.js:11574:81)
>       at /js/angular/angular.js:11660:26
>       at Scope.$eval (/js/angular/angular.js:12724:28)
>       at Scope.$digest (/js/angular/angular.js:12536:31)
>       at Function.$httpBackend.flush (/tests/angular-mock.js:1447:20)
>       at Object. (/tests/tests.js:113:29)

if I add console statements throughout my code. i can see that `marvelRepository.fetch(1)` is getting called. however `.$promise.then()` doesn't appear to execute.

And what doesn't make sense to me is the 1st two lines of the error. First it states an unexpected request was made and then it says an expected call to the url was made. and it's the same url.

any ideas on what I'm overlooking?

**Update**
I updated the structure of the test. setting up both `when` and `expect` calls.

I also found if I change my backend calls from `when('get', ...` to `when('GET', ...` i receive the following test error

```
undefined: undefined
```

No stacktrace or line numbers, but undefined.  Reviewing the original error it states

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET url....
Expected get url...
```

so I'm wondering if it's failing because of the case sensitivity comparing the request method. However, I think it's a timing issue. The service is injected and the method is called, however the `promise.then(cb)` doesn't execute. But maybe it's not firing because the request methods don't match so $httpbackend doesn't return?

Answer (score 0):

In a BeforeEach you need to use `.when()` instead of `.expect()`.

```
httpBackend
.when('GET', 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=123&hash=abc123&limit=20&offset=0&ts=20140601073322')
.respond({ data: { results: characters, offset: 2, limit: 20, total: 100 } });
```

Using `.expect()` is typically done in an assertion, not setup.

Comment: the only difference i can see between when and expect is the second line of the error. if i use `when` it says "no more requests expected". if i use `expect` it says "expected gateway.marvel...."

Comment: the 1st line of the error states "unexpected request" could I be setting up the backend too soon?

Comment: Your inner expect()s are unneeded unless you have to override the URL. The case of the HTTP verbs matters, so always use caps. To help isolate which test is failing, you can xit() all of them out but one (if you are using Jasmine 1.x) or use iit() to run just that one test (if you are using Jasmine 2.x). Focus on one test at a time and it should help clear things up.

Comment: thanks @MBielksi! I was able to simplify the tests more based on this feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. The issue is the use of promises and deferred execution. I need to call `$scope.apply()` as well and '$httpBackend.flush()'

here is a passing test

```
describe('characterController', function () {
    var characterUrl = 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1';
    var character;

    beforeEach(function () {
        character = { name: 'Wolverine'};

        httpBackend.whenGET(characterUrl).respond({ data: { results: [character] } });
    });

    it('should be able to get character with id of 1', function () {
        controller('characterController', { $scope: scope, $routeParams: { id: 1 } });

        scope.$apply();//execute promises
        httpBackend.flush(); //process http requests

        expect(scope.character).toEqual(character);
    });
});
```